When might a UK border control officer decide not to stamp passport on entry?
I am not a UK citizen. I am a BRP holder who lives in the UK for work. Everytime I come back to the UK after a short international trip, the border control officer adds an entry stamp to my passport. This has happened everytime until my last re-entry into the UK a few months ago.
But this month (Dec 2024) when I re-entered the UK after a short international trip, the border control officer did not add an entry stamp to my passport. This happened in the LHR airport. I don't know if the officer simply forgot to add the stamp or if there has been a change in the process due to which stamps are no longer required on entry.
I'd like to know when might a border control officer decide not to stamp my passport on re-entry? If there has been a change of process due to which passport entry stamps are no longer required, is there any communication or documentation about this on the gov.uk website?
And if the officer really did forget to add the stamp, would it have any consequences in the future?

I am not aware of any comprehensive official communication on this (hence no answer from me) but in general stamps are clearly being phased out in favour of other systems (APIS, ETA, eVisa). Lots of chatter online from people in your particular situation (BRP holders) whose passports are not being stamped anymore, seems to be the new normal (e.g. reddit).

Note that your BRP will most likely expire at the end of the month and need to be replaced by an eVisa on your UKVI account. Note also that you may be eligible to use eGates depending on your citizenship or via the Registered Traveller service.

@Relaxed Thanks for linking to the interesting Reddit thread. Although that thread is a year old, I got a physical entry stamp on my passport only a few months ago after arriving in LHR. So if they do not require physical stamps anymore, it looks like this requirement is not applied uniformly for all cases. That's what makes me wonder how the officer decides whether to add an entry stamp or not.

@jcaron Yes, I have an eVisa now but the border control officer asked for my physical BRP card at LHR airport. I wasn't eligible for eGates. I had a border control officer physically inspect my passport and physical BRP card.

@WorldTraveller Yes, it doesn't seem consistent, some people have reported not getting stamps as far back as 2020, how it's being rolled out is very unclear but the direction of travel seems clear. Personally, I have only been to the UK as a visitor, we don't have the same citizenships and it's the same thing, no stamps for quite some time, ETA rolled out at different times (but there was some official communication about that).

Rather than get an answer here which might not be 100% correct, why not ring UK Border Force and ask them if there has been a change of policy or just an oversight. They are the experts and in a position to give an authoritative answer. A quick google found this telephone number for Border Force at Heathrow Terminal 3. Other numbers were given for other terminals. 020 8745 5002.
